# why doesn't it show as a type `float`

Tags: python, floating-point, command-prompt

I was just messing around with python command prompt when I discovered something, that I personally didn't know of.

This is one mystery that I'm trying to solve:

```
num = int(5) / 2

num == float # False
```

I found it weird that it didn't return `True`. So i tried with other operators.

```
num == int # False
num == str # False
```

they all return False, but when i check which `type` it is. It gives me this.

```
type(num) # Float
```

Shouldn't it have returned `True` when i compared it to the `float` operator?

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: you comparing values (instances) to class definiation

Comment: You should look at using [isinstance(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `num` contains the value `2.5`, it doesn't hold the type `float` so `num == float` can't be true

---

What can be true is

- comparing to the value `2.5`

  ```
  print(num == 2.5)                # true
  ```
- comparing num's type to the `float` type

  ```
  print(type(num) == float)        # true
  ```
- checking if the type of `num` is `float`

  ```
  print(isinstance(num, float))    # true
  ```

Comment: I get it. You can't compare a `type` to a value, it's just not  possible. But i can compare a type to type or a value to a value. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @bliboy you 'can' compare a type to a value, just it'd be false, they are no the same

Comment: so it will just keep returning `False`  when you are comparing a value to a type. unless you use a `not` operator.

Comment: @bliboy In fact yes, you just need to think : what is `num` ? => it contains 2.5, it is not the TYPE float itself, it is a VALUE of type float

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing an object(of type `float`) with a class(`float` in this case).
To get True, you should compare the type of `num` with `float`:

```
type(num) == float
```

You can also do:

```
isinstance(num, float)
```

which is better according to PEP8(Coding style convention for python).

Both will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `num = int(5) / 2` gives you in result 2.5 not float, when you are checking the type of variable you have to write something like this

`type(num) == float`
not
`num == float`
because num is 2.5 not float